# How to create a 'global event' in actionscript / flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, events, globalevent

What is the best way to create a 'global event' in flex/actionscript - preferably using a static class?

I want to raise an event to indicate that a stylesheet is loaded in order to show components that require that stylesheet. So I want each portion of the application that requires a style from the stylesheet to listen to an event telling it that the styles are all loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**robotlegs**](http://www.robotlegs.org/), simple and [**Singleton free**](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/root-cause-of-singletons.html)!

Answer (score 1):

Make a [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and add listeners to it, nice and simple.